# Meaning of ものなんだろう in this sentence

Tags: sentence, sentence-final-particles, particle-mono

[image]

What function does the もの server in this sentence? Wouldn't it work with just なんだろう?

He should be saying that the people who followed the idol group to the very beginning are even more emotional.

But what ものなんだろう adds here?

Answer (score 2):

This sentence has 感動物【かんどうもの】, which is a fixed compound noun that refers to a work/event that moves/inspires/impresses people. なんだろう is simply explanatory-(な)のだ followed by だろう.

感動物 is used like this:

- この小説は感動物ですよ。
  This novel is moving!
- 感動物の映画
  heart-touching movie
- 友人の結婚式に行ってきました。感動物でした！
  I went to the wedding of my friend. I was moved/impressed!

> 古参の方たち(に)はもっと感動ものなんだろうな。
> (It) should be even more impressive to old fans.

Answer (score 0):

Transcription:

> 古参の方たちはもっと感動ものなんだろうな。

I guess it is shorter from (deduce it from context):

> 古参の方たちはもっと感動**した**ものなんだろうな。

Literal translation:

> It is a thing (なんだろうな) that the "long serving" people (古参方たち) are the ones (もの) who were moved more (もっと感動した).

感動 is a noun, so I am a little troubled about it being followed by もの.

なんだろうな gives you the idea of a very safe guess.

もの plays a crucial role here. The sentence wouldn't make sense without it. In English we can go without it.

> They are the ones who were moved more.

> They were moved more.

But in this sentence the structure is something like this:

People A = People B

もの is needed to make the "People B" part.